# Kafka consumer : Resetting offset for partition xxxx1-0 to offset 25143.Every time I start it

Tags: linux, java

Topic-A：

```
o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=group-5] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=group-5] (Re-)joining group
o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=group-5] Successfully joined group with generation 1
o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=group-5] Setting newly assigned partitions [A1-0]
o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=group-5] Resetting offset for partition A1-0 to offset 25143.
```

last message:

```
o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=group-5] Resetting offset for partition A1-0 to offset 25143.
```

This causes me to reset the offset every time I start,Let's say I run to number 25200,then I turn off that,the offset is reset to 25143 the next time I start,
but I want to continue with the last offset.

This is another topic,and this is the normal result I want:
Topic-wallet：

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - Cluster ID: iQU30Fo1TViA2rkH9cxVYQ
o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=wallet-1] Discovered group coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=wallet-1] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=wallet-1] (Re-)joining group
o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=wallet-1] Successfully joined group with generation 13
o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=wallet-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [blockaddresscomplete3-0]
```

How should I set Topic-A.

Answer (score 1):

I had experienced the same issue. THe reason behind is that retention period of messages in input topic is passed. Please run console consumer command and find the count of messages in your topic.
I hope this advice resolves.